# Should I say "Which city" or "What city" - in the following context?

Tags: word-choice

In the following context, which of them is acceptable to the English native speakers?

1) **Which** city are you living?

2) **What** city are you living?

or

1) **What** city have you come from?

2) **Which** city have you come from?

Answer (score 7):

*Which* implies a selection among a known set of options, for example:

> We have chapter members here from New York City, San Diego, and Miami. Which city are you from?

If you don't have any idea where the person comes from, *what* would be more common.

> Hi! I'm from Timbuktu. What city are you from?

The same rules apply to asking about the city someone lives in, but please note the change I made above (*do* you come from, not *have* you come from, unless you mean "I see you just got off an airplane! What city have you just come from?"). For "living", you should say:

> What/which city are you living **in**.

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences should be used with "which" to convey the meaning you are intending to express.

> In which city are you living? Rather formal
>
> Which city are you living in? Conversational
>
> From which city have you come from? Rather formal
>
> Which city have you come from? Conversational